# how to get data in sql when a one table have more than one foriegn keys of a table

Tags: sql, database-design, join

I have three tables in my database called `supplier`, `materials`, `categories`.

In the materials table it have a `supplier id` as foreign key and each material going with 
three categories. I have keep that categories by using `id` of category table. So there are three fields in material table to keep ids of categories. It means the material table have three foreign keys of category table.

Now my problem is how to select data from material table using sql join with supplier and categories table.

Comment: Please post your table definitions as create table statements, it makes it A) much clearer to use and B) much easier for us to start helping you. Can you also post any query that you have written so far to give us an idea what exactly you're stuck with (and to show us that you've actually tried something yourself).

Comment: You can `JOIN` the same table several times (if needed) each time using a different `ON` expression and specifying their own `table aliases`.

Comment: Please (at the very least) post `sample data` and the `expected result`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM
    supplier
    JOIN materials ON
        supplier.supplier_id = materials.supplier_id
    JOIN categories ON (
        materials.category_id1 = categories.category_id
        OR materials.category_id2 = categories.category_id
        OR materials.category_id3 = categories.category_id
    )
```

But you should really reconsider the way you connect between `materials` and `categories`. This looks like a regular many-to-many relationship, that can be represented by a "junction" (aka "link") table in between these two tables. This would allow you to have unlimited categories per material.